# "Enable Partner Super User " Checkbox missing from Digital Experiences Settings page

Tags: partner-communities

I am system admin for my developer org with CUstomize Application checked. I have Partner community enabled but for some reason I don't see "Enable Partner Super User " checkbox under SETUP-->Digital Experiences --> Settings page. Any idea as to why ?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable Partner Super User  access is a feature need to enable from the back-end. Raise a case with Salesforce with all relevant org details, you will get assistance in enabling that.

Check below doc detailing requisite licence and functionality enabled upon buying.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_partners_enable_features.htm&type=5

Comment: I do have all the relevant licenses and role ...do I still need to raise a case with salesforce ?